# Can I safely add a new partition?

Tags: partitioning, 13.10

I'm pretty sure that I only formatted a small portion of my HD when I installed Saucy. I'd like to create a new partition to store Podcasts on (having learned the hard way the perils of a home partition that grows to infinity). But I'm out of practice and I'm not totally confident that I'm not missing something.

Lsblk reports:

```
amanda@mona:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                       8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                       8:2    0   244M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                       8:3    0 237.8G  0 part  
  ├─mona--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  38.8G  0 lvm   /
  └─mona--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm   
    └─cryptswap1 (dm-2)    252:2    0   7.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

And fdisk reports:

```
amanda@mona:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd3827d00

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   500118191   250059095+  ee  GPT
```

I should add that a friend helped me with the install and I specifically recall that we didn't partition it all up, but that he did the partitioning and made me a relatively small partition so I could do my own partitioning later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using lvm so you can use the `lvcreate` command to create a new logical volume, then format it and mount it in a location of your choosing.  Or you can just enlarge the size of your root volume wtih `sudo lvresize -L +50G mona-vg/root` and `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/mona--vg-root`.

Or ... id your Volume Group

```
$ sudo vgs
VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
mona-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 237.76g 191.20g
```

And then id your logical volumes:

```
$ sudo lvs
LV     VG      Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
root   mona-vg -wi-ao--- 38.74g                                           
swap_1 mona-vg -wi-ao---  7.82g
```

And then add a new logical volume with

```
$ sudo lvcreate --name music --size 10G mona-vg
```

Comment: Ok. Reading this now: http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/04/27/managing-disk-space-with-lvm.html

Comment: Added my steps to the answer, but yes. LVM was the redirection that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new partition is only "safe", when there is free space left or "non-partitioned" space.

With gparted it is possible to "resize" a partition, but not all file-systems allow this. You can view in gparted which files-systems are supported for to resize there partitions. For example it is impossible to resize a xfs-filesystem.

To get to option of resizing, you need to click concerning partition in gparted only once, then right-click on this marked partition. There in popping-up menue is entry of "resize". But be really sure and look at least three times at : - which cylinder/byte-position is beginning of new partition - and - which cylinder/byte-position is end of new partition. Check if this is really correct for to avoid loss of datas or else "doom".

Comment: @Amanda - inform me if this answer helped or too "noobish".